# Python : string replace with parenthesis sign

Tags: python, string

I am tring to use the replace function to modify the following string:

```
'hello (world)'
```

to

```
'hello \(world)'
```

However when i run

```
'hello (world)'.replace('(', '\(')
```

it returns

```
'hello \\(world)'
```

Any idea how to achieve the intended output?

EDIT: 
the problem is that i am trying to pass those new arguments to a mysql query and the double backslah DO end up in the query, making it invalid... `'SELECT datetime, actual, forecast, prior FROM all-data.indicators_ft WHERE country="United States" AND name = "CPI \\(ex Food & Energy\\) % m/m"'`

Comment: The reason you get that output is because backslashes must be escaped in strings in Python. Thus, Python automatically inserts an escape character in your string.

Comment: Instead of allowing the REPL to display the `repr` of the string, actually use `print` and you wont see the double back slash. `repr` is formatted to allow the recreation of the object using `eval` and since a string literal requires the escape character, it will be seen when the string is displayed via `repr`

Comment: @leaf Using the following string `'CPI (ex Food & Energy) % m/m'.replace('(', '\\(')` (with the escaped backslash) also returns the same wrong result...

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing the interactive python shell output versus that ACTUAL contents of the string:

```
>>>hello (world)'.replace('(', '\(')
hello \\(world)
```

but

```
>>>print 'hello (world)'.replace('(', '\(')
hello \(world)
```

Comment: the problem is that i am trying to pass those new arguments to a mysql query and the double backslah DO end up in the query, making it invalid... `'SELECT datetime, actual, forecast, prior FROM `all-data`.indicators_ft WHERE country="United States" AND name = "CPI \\(ex Food & Energy\\) % m/m"'`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly:

```
>>> print('hello (world)'.replace('(', '\('))
hello \(world)
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the link and show the code. Lines starting with at least four spaces are formatted as code. Your answer could be improved by explaining why OP was seeing th incorrect result.

Comment: @deathstroke the problem is that i am trying to pass those new arguments to a mysql query and the double backslah DO end up in the query, making it invalid... `'SELECT datetime, actual, forecast, prior FROM `all-data`.indicators_ft WHERE country="United States" AND name = "CPI \\(ex Food & Energy\\) % m/m"'`